# Django. Проблема с валидацией в проекте

Tags: python, django

Заданы валидаторы в модели, но при отправки формы вместо текста валидации выбивает:
 ValueError at /mac/mac_add/

The view conference.views.new_form didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Самое интересное что в Django admin все корректно работает. То же самое и с ключем unique. При отправки формы выдает ту же ошибку. Не могу понять где ошибка

**view.py**

@login_required(redirect_field_name='home')
def new_form(request):

```
AD_username = request.user.first_name
AD_lastname = request.user.last_name
user = Conference.objects.get(first_name=AD_username, last_name=AD_lastname)

if request.method == 'POST':
    i = 1
    form2 = MacaddForm(request.POST)
    user_current = user.current_device
    user_max = user.max_device
    mac_now = user.mac_set.count() + 1
    messages.error(request, 'Максимально допустимое количество MAC-адресов')
    if mac_now > user_max:
        return redirect('home')


    if form2.is_valid():
        new_mac = form2.save(commit=False)
        new_mac.user_id_id = user.id
        new_mac.save()
        Conference.objects.filter(id=user.id).update(current_device=mac_now)
        return redirect('home')

else:
    form2 = MacaddForm()
    current_device = user.max_device
    return render(request, 'Test.html', {'form': form2, 'current_device':current_device})
```

**models.py**

class MAC(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='id')
    MAC_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='MAC-адресс', blank=False ,null=False, unique=True, validators=[RegexValidator(
        regex='[0-9a-fA-F]{2}:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}',
        message='Некоректно введённый MAC-адрес. Используйте форму XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX',
        code='invalid_MAC')])
    device = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Название девайса')
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='Время публицации')
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='user_id')

**forms.py**

class MacaddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MAC
        fields = ('MAC_address', 'device')

Comment: Очевидно, что если форма не is_valid() то вьюха ничего не возвращает и всё ломается. А почему оно не is_valid() - это надо было делать вывод ошибок формы в ветке else

Comment: Так else же возвращает просто вывод формы. Там нету ничего такого из-за чего бы форма "ломалась". Как тогда можно правильно дописать else чтоб проходила валидация на уровне модели?

Comment: Не тот else. После is_valid() у вас никакого else вообще нету и его нужно добавить (или каким-либо образом объединить со следующим else)

Comment: Сделал в описание ниже. траница уже не "падает", но ошибку валидации заданую в модели не выдает.

Comment: Ну да, вы вместо вывода ошибки просто создали новую пустую форму, в которой никаких ошибок изначально нет, поэтому и не выдаёт

Comment: Подскажите плиз, как сделать вывод ошибок записанных в валидаторе? В Предыдущем проекте ошибки в форме по валидатором выводились автоматически, я ничего не прописывал. В этом проекте по какой-то причине не хочет их выводить. Руками я их не должен прописывать, ошибки уже прописаны в модели. Заранее спасибо

Comment: В документации есть примеры, там всё корректно с выводом ошибок сделано https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так, страница уже не "падает", но ошибку валидации заданую в модели не выдает:

```
    if form2.is_valid():
        new_mac = form2.save(commit=False)
        new_mac.user_id_id = user.id
        new_mac.save()
        Conference.objects.filter(id=user.id).update(current_device=mac_now)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form2 = MacaddForm()
        return render(request, 'Test.html', {'form': form2})

else:
    form2 = MacaddForm()
    current_device = user.max_device
    return render(request, 'Test.html', {'form': form2, 'current_device':current_device})
```

Comment: MAC_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='MAC-адресс', blank=False ,null=False, unique=True, validators=[RegexValidator(
        regex='[0-9a-fA-F]{2}:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}',
        message='Некоректно введённый MAC-адрес. Используйте форму XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX',
        code='invalid_MAC')])

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в том что строчке return оказался лишний пробел) "Программисты, будь-те осторожны с пробелами" )
Нужно чтоб было так:

```
else:
    form2 = MacaddForm()
return render(request, 'add_mac.html', {'form': form2})
```

всем спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Классная штука - это в else спринтить ошибки валидации формы. Очень помогает.

```
 print(form2.errors)
```